# Variable Scope with setTimeout & clearTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope

While studying variable scope there has been one thing I can't seem to figure out. For example of two elements. If the first is hovered upon then its sibling appears. If you mouse-out of the initial element the sibling will disappear through a setTimeout which is stored within a variable expression. If you happened to hover over the sibling a clearTimeout function is called and is set to fade out in the callback.

In regards to scope what I'm not understanding is how exactly the `timer` variable is recognized in the `clearTimeout` function. I tried to `console.log(timer)` but just got numeric values. While the following works I'd like to know why and how? In other words how does the second hover method call know what's inside the timer variable since its out of scope?

```
var timer;

$('p:eq(1)').hide();

$('p').first().hover(function() {
  $(this).next().fadeIn();
}, function() {
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    $('p:eq(1)').fadeOut();
  }, 1000);
  // console.log(timer);
});

$('p:eq(1)').hover(function() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
}, function() {
  $('p:eq(1)').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Comment: You got numeric values because that's how it works.  `setTimeout` returns a number that identifies that timeout.

Comment: Great thanks for clearing that part up. How exactly is `timer` variable recognized within the sibling's `hover` method though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `clearTimeout` takes not just a `setTimeout`, but its ID. Here's what I found it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.clearTimeout):
[image]

So, when you set a timeout, it returns a specific ID for reference and so `clearTimeout` will work. Again, per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout):
[image]

**Since you set `timer` on the global scope, each of your functions has access to it.**

Thanks for asking a question that taught me something! (I didn't know `setTimeout` returned anything)

Comment: Yep, thats why you dont want to do var timeoutID = within a deeply nested function because you'll never be able to retrieve what that ID actually is unless its declared in a function within the same scope as the processing of clearTimeout (or you use external storage)

Comment: Thanks! So in a sense the `timeoutID` is hidden and retrieved by the `clearTimeout` function behind the scenes?

Comment: No problem Carl! timeoutID is saved by you on the global scope in the `timer` variable, meaning everything has access to it. Read http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html#p_N7xZ5k5OET for more information about scopes and how they work in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Simple..  The timer itself is stored in memory though the 'timer' variable which you have defined in the same scope as the sibling event bindings.  Therefore,  the timer variable is acccessable by directly calling it with 'timer' in any sibling or child scopes.   Had you declared the 'var timer' part within the function like this:

```
 function() {
  var timer;
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    $('p:eq(1)').fadeOut();
  }, 1000);
```

The result would be that clearTimeout(timer) would not be within the scope and result in an unknown member error.